# Google maps reverse geocoding always responds with 602 (Unknown Address) on server side

Tags: python, django, google-maps

I have server-side code that calls the Google geocoding API, like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=40.714224,-73.961452&output=json&sensor=false&key=API_KEY
```

where `API_KEY` is my API key. I get a JSON reply, as expected, but the reponse is always `602` (Unknown Address). Is my URL wrong? (I've also tried the URL in the [Google docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html#ReverseGeocoding), but that returns a `status: 'REQUEST_DENIED'`.

What else could be wrong?

**Update:**
Well, it seems to actually be a mistake in my implementation, not the URL. This was how I did it:

```
api_params = {
            'q': '40.714224,-73.961452',
            'sensor': 'false',
            'key': KEY,
            'output': 'json'
        }

    # make the api call
    http_response = urllib.urlopen('http://maps.google.com/maps/geo',
                                        urllib.urlencode(api_params))
    r = json.load(http_response)
```

but changing it to:

```
  api_params = {
            #'q': str(lat) + ',' + str(lng),
            'q': '40.714224,-73.961452',
            'sensor': 'false',
            'key': KEY,
            'output': 'json'
        }

    # make the api call
    http_response = urllib.urlopen('http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q='+api_params['q']+'&output=json&sensor=false&key='+api_params['key'])
    r = json.load(http_response)
    print r
```

fixes the problem. So my new question is, what's wrong with the first one?

Comment: Have you tried this in your browser?  I took the URL as is and it game me back an accurate result.

Comment: hmm.. you're right.. that's strange... maybe a mistake in my implementation! I'll get back on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one executes POST request, the second - GET request.

You may also want to use the urllib.urlencode function for concatenation.

But the easiest way is to use geopy.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a HTTP watcher to make sure that this is the actual URL that is being sent within your application.  There could be a chance that it isn't being encoded correctly or maybe is being incorrectly assembled.  Since you aren't getting request denied and we were able to get a good response when we viewed it directly it seems that could be the best place to start.  Hope that helps!